# Remove Application Files in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a **WPF project** in Visual studio, and suddenly `Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll` has been included in Application Files. I don't know where it comes from and how to remove it. I know I can set Publish Status to Exclude, but does anyone know why it is there? I have made a text search in all files included in the solution but I'm not able to find it anywhere:

[image]

Comment: It is pretty popular in Nuget packages.  Has something to do with WIF getting integrated into the framework at version 4.5, probably is just a reference assembly that hides the differences with [TypeForwardedTo].  Since it is not in the GAC anymore, the publish wizard thinks it needs to be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might be a dependent dll to any reference you added to a project . try removing the reference and check whether it is dependent or not .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found the name of the mystery files in the other DLLs in the bin folder.  VS appears to be detecting the dependencies and including the proper DLLs.

Try this PowerShell script to see if you can find hidden references:

`get-childitem -file -recurse | Select-String -Pattern your_mystery_file | group path | select name`